# jQuery tabs not working w/.hide() and .show()

Tags: jquery

```
$('#tab-1').show();
$('#tab-2').hide();
$('#tab-2').click(function() {
    $('#tab-1').hide();
    $('#tab-2').show();
});
```

Why won't this work?  When I click the  with the id of tab-2 it appends #tab-2 to the URL but doesn't show the content.

Comment: How can you click on a hidden element?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return false;` to that click method or it'll follow through and try and navigate to somewhere on the page called #tab-2 (the # character was originally meant to allow linking to sections in the same HTML document)

```
$('#tab-2').click(function() {
    $('#tab-1').hide();
    $('#tab-2').show();
    return false;
});
```

Or alternatively you can pass an event and use preventDefault()

```
$('#tab-2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tab-1').hide();
    $('#tab-2').show();
});
```

However the comment above still stands. If you hide #tab-2, how can you click on it? Is there a typo in your HTML?

Comment: I tried both and it's still not showing the new content and hiding the old.

Comment: OP might want to keep the default anchored link behaviour. We're yet to resolve how they are able to click a hidden element!

Comment: @Moob, I assumed he wouldn't want to keep default behaviour since he's showing and hiding tabs. On the topic of how he clicked on a hidden element, I doubt we'll ever know.

Comment: Probably a fair assumption :)